# Download one array from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

Quite a simple question really but can't find the answer anywhere.

On the Parse data browser, there are lots of users and they each have an array with a bunch of string values, how do i download just one of these arrays from just one user into an `NSArray` of string values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the objectId of the user? or the username?  Say it's the username:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"Vladimir Putin"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (objects.count) {
            PFUser *vladimir = objects[0];
            NSLog(@"Putins strings are %@" [vladimir objectForKey:@"theArrayColumn"]);
        } else {
            // where are you Vlad?
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

It's easier if you know the object id.  Then use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`: instead of find.  (To be clear, you'll be downloading the object and it's array property.  There's no way that I know of to get just a property).

Comment: Can I then to get just the array of string values say `NSArray *array = [vladmir objectForKey:@"theArrayColumn"];`

Comment: Without fetching the user that contains that array?  No.  You could write a cloud code function that took a username or id and returned that user's array column, but I think that's the only alternative.